# Ubuntu Mount an NFS share into an another ubuntu VM via local-only connection

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, nfs, virtualbox-networking

Over my host machine I have setup an NFS server with the following settings into the file `/etc/exports`:

```
/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/C++/intelSGX/MyFirstEnclave *(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
```

Also to the host I have provided the following `ufw` firewall configurations:

```
Anywhere on vboxnet0       ALLOW       2049                       (log)
Anywhere (v6) on vboxnet0  ALLOW       2049 (v6)                  (log)

Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   80 on vboxnet0
```

Where `vboxnet0` is a host-only virtualbox network:

[image: Virtualbox network settings]

And has this settings:
[image: Network settings of host only adapter]

Also over my Host I run `rpcinfo -p | grep nfs` with the following result:

```
100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
```

Over my the virtual machine I have the following network interfaces:

```
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:4e:5d:88  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe4e:5d88/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:26355 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12806 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:20957730 (20.9 MB)  TX bytes:777044 (777.0 KB)

enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:80:69:57  
          inet addr:192.168.56.102  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe80:6957/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3688 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8851 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:351598 (351.5 KB)  TX bytes:762540 (762.5 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)  TX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)
```

Where `enp0s8` is a host only interface. But when I run:

```
sudo mount 192.168.56.1:/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/C++/intelSGX/MyFirstEnclave ~/MyFirstEnclave
```

I get the following error:

```
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

I also tried to do a `netcat 192.168.56.1 2049` but showed no result.

Do you have any Idea why that happens?

## Edit 1

As suggested on comments, I disabled the firewall. Now when I do:

```
sudo mount 192.168.56.1:/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/C++/intelSGX/MyFirstEnclave ~/MyFirstEnclave
```

I get the following error:

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.56.1:/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/C++/intelSGX/MyFirstEnclave
```

## Edit 2:

I also on the host did `sudo exportfs -a` and I get the error:

```
exportfs: /etc/exports [1]: Neither 'subtree_check' or 'no_subtree_check' specified for export "*:/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/C++/intelSGX/MyFirstEnclave".
  Assuming default behaviour ('no_subtree_check').
  NOTE: this default has changed since nfs-utils version 1.0.x
```

Comment: Dimitrios, I suggest you disable the firewall until you have the configuration working as you planned.

Comment: On the host, whats the response to: `sudo exportfs`

Comment: I created a similar configuration on my Xubuntu and a VMware client and I too received an access denied when trying to mount the share. It turned out I needed to change the Network Adapter setting on the client from NAT to Bridged. Then I was able to mount the share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over the virtual machine run the `mount` command like that:

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o proto=tcp,port=2049 192.168.56.1:/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/C++/intelSGX/MyFirstEnclave ~/MyFirstEnclave
```

On the command above take a look over the `-o proto=tcp,port=2049` and `-t nfs` params that you are telling directly to mount an an nfs share using `tcp` protocol and the port `2049`.

Then you can unmount it via:

```
sudo fusermount -u ~/MyFirstEnclave
```

Furthermore the following `gufw` settings are recommended (gui is in greek but also you can understand fro the element position of the form):

[image: gufw firewall settings for nfs]

Also over your vm if you want permanent mount then try to put the following settings into your `/etc/fstab`:

```
192.168.56.1:/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/C++/intelSGX/MyFirstEnclave /home/user/MyFirstEnclave nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr,tcp,port=2049
```

Please notice the `tcp,port=2049` section of the entry that you are telling to use tcp and connent into server's `2049` port.